# Reading scanf parameter from C to assembly causes cmd to crash

Tags: c, assembly, parameters, nasm, scanf

so basically the title says it all. If the parameter was acquired from scanf, the cmd prompt crashes whereas when the parameter is fixed, there is no issue.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int sum();

int main()
{
   int a1, a2, x;
   scanf("%d", &a1)
   /* a1 = 0; */
   a2 = 3;
   x = sum(a1, a2);
   printf("%d + %d = %d", a1, a2, x);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

NASM code:

```
segment .text
global _sum

_sum: push ebp              ;create stack frame
mov ebp, esp            ;save stack
mov eax, [ebp + 8]  ;first parameter
mov edx, [ebp + 12] ;second parameter
add eax, edx            ;add. EAX is the default paremeter to pass back
pop ebp
leave
ret
```

Comment: Remove `pop ebp`. `Leave` does the equivalent of `mov esp, ebp` `pop ebp`. You have effectively done `pop ebp` twice. See the [Instruction Set Reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_154.html)

Comment: Although not part of your problem, it is a good idea to create proper prototypes for your functions so that type checking can be done by the _C_ compiler. change `extern int sum();` to `extern int sum(int a, int b);`

Comment: where is `sum` actually defined?  Since `sum()` is a function, much better to just have prototype rather than an `extern`.   so this line: `extern int sum();` should be: `int sum( int, int);`   The statement that calls `scanf()` is missing the terminating semicolon ';'

Comment: @user3629249 `sum` is defined in the assembler file as `_sum`. This implies though that the OP is likely compiling on Win32 platform where the `_` needs to be specified in the assembler file when using _CDECL_ calling convention is used (unless overridden)